# How to dump .text section to an output file using radare2?

Tags: hex, dump, portable-executable

I have this radare2 running on my windows10, and trying to get the .text section of a PE format executable file. Shall I first have to know what is the size of .text section and do a dump within the address range? Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Have you tried using plain old linux utility `objdump`? (You can have it on windows with mingw.)

Comment: I will try it, thanks for sharing!

Comment: this is a better fit for [reverseengineering.se]

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you could do this.

You can dump the .text section to file as a C style string of bytes using the command:

```
pcs section_end..text-section..text @ section..text > myfile.txt
```

ie "\x90\x90\x41\x41".

See 'pc?' for help about other output formats.

'section_end..text' and 'section..text' are markers or bookmarks of the addresses of the start and end of your .text section.  radare2 identifies the sections and creates the markers for you (called flags in radare2).  So we're suubtraction .text end address from .text start address to get length of the section

You could also use 'wtf' for raw binary dump.  Something like:

```
wtf myfile section_end..text-section..text @ section..text
```

- 'wtf' for write to file
- myfile is your filename
- subtract end from start to get length
- '@ section..text' to tell it what seek position to begin dumping
  from.

Comment: It says `|ERROR| Invalid command 'pcs section_end..text-section..text @ section..text' (0x70)`.

Answer (score 0):

What's your .text sections name?  In a file I see .text.0 as there were more than one section in the PE file.  So add the number following - .text.<##>

e.g., pcs section_end..text.0-section..text.0 @ section..text.0 > myfile.txt

Although this outputs one long text line of the .text section in the file:

"\x8b\x9c ... \x67\xf1\xff\x00\x00"

to write the .text.<##> section to a file change the command a bit too:

wtf  section_end..text.0-section..text.0 @ section..text.0

Change the number, 0, to that for your .text.<##> section number. Use the command:

S

to list all the sections